# OKHTTP Android sending POST request as formdata with image

Tags: java, android, api, okhttp

I have an API POST request that takes in form/data with both text (strings) and 1 image file. In postman, this is what it looks like, and it works perfectly :)

[image: POST Request on postman that works by taking in form/data strings and an image]

I am trying to send the same thing through a POST request on an android app through OKHTTP. Here is the code that I wrote:

```
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse(getMimeType(imageFile.toURI().toURL().toString()));
        requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("imageFile", imageFile.getName(), RequestBody.create(imageFile, mediaType))
                .addFormDataPart("machineKey", machineKey)
                .addFormDataPart("authToken", authToken)
                .addFormDataPart("UIID", UIID)
                .addFormDataPart("localItemID", localItemID)
                .addFormDataPart("itemName", itemName)
                .addFormDataPart("itemDescription", itemDescription)
                .addFormDataPart("itemPrice", itemPrice)
                .addFormDataPart("itemStock", itemStock)
                .addFormDataPart("itemAge", itemAge)
                .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(URLString)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();
    System.out.println("POST: calling: " +URLString);
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Here are a few notes to keep in mind :)

1. imageFile is the file if the image (and the file is guaranteed to always exist, and is accessible)
2. all strings are never null

   `(getMimeType(imageFile.toURI().toURL().toString())` will return `"image/jpeg"` or `"image/*"`, I have tried both

I am running this code asynchronously, and this code will post the string values correctly, but for some reason will not correctly post the image file. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate your problem. not posting correctly means what? API call is happening but img not reflecting? getting error? have you debugged the code?

Comment: Yeah, so my api will read through and if the response of that string of MultipartFile is empty or null, it will just not update that section of the item. So basically the API is finding that the file being sent is either null or empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually figured it out... turns out the files names I were sending were not sanitized, so some files being sent had illegal characters in its file name, so I got that fixed! thanks! :)

Comment: How did you sanitize?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to set the content-type request header:
`.addHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data")`

Answer (score 1):

**I am Using Below code To Send my form Data with Access Token**

```
String directoryPath = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + File.separator  + context.getString(R.string.pdf_folder) + "/";
File pdfFile = new File(directoryPath +"ImagesToPDF.pdf");
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();

  MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");

  RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                               .addFormDataPart("UploadFile",pdfFile.toString(),
                                          RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),
                                                new File(pdfFile.toString())))
                                .build();
                        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                .url("http://ip:port/V1/User/UserUploadingFile")
                                .method("POST", body)
                                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token)
                                .build();
                        Response response = null;
                        Call call = client.newCall(request);

                        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {

                                String responsee = response.body().string();

                                Log.e("response ", "onResponse(): " + responsee );
                                int code=  response.code();

                                if (code == 200){
                                }else if(code == 401){
                                }else if(code == 404){

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,LoginActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {

                                Log.e("HttpService", "onFailure() Request was: " + request);

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                        });
```